# ListBox binding results in doubled items

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a very weird problem.  I am binding `ListBox.ItemSource` to an `ObservableCollection`. I subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of the collection if any items are added, I show the window with the `ListBox` that is bound to the collection.  The first time I do this, the `ListBox` shows only one item as it should.  The second time however, the `ListBox` which is in a newly created `Window` shows two items.  I have verified that the `ObservableCollection` never has more than one item in it. What the heck is going on?

Here is the code in my view model.

```
    public ObservableCollection<AlarmItemViewModel> RaisedAlarms
    {
        get { return _raisedAlarms; }
        set { _raisedAlarms = value; RaisePropertyChanged("RaisedAlarms"); }
    }

    protected override void OnAlarmRaised(AlarmItem a_alarmItem)
    {
        var activeAlarmItems = from alarmItem in RaisedAlarms
                               select alarmItem.AlarmItem;

        if (!activeAlarmItems.Contains(a_alarmItem))
            RaisedAlarms.Add(new AlarmItemViewModel(this, a_alarmItem));
    }

    private void OnActiveAlarmsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            if (_alarmRaiseWindow == null)
            {
                _alarmRaiseWindow = new SetupWindow();
                _alarmRaiseWindow.Title = "Alarm Raised";
                _alarmRaiseWindow.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
                _alarmRaiseWindow.Topmost = true;
                _alarmRaiseWindow.Content = new AlarmRaise();
                _alarmRaiseWindow.DataContext = this;
                _alarmRaiseWindow.Closed += OnAlarmNotifyClosed;
            }
        }

        if (!RaisedAlarms.Any() && _alarmRaiseWindow != null)
        {
            _alarmRaiseWindow.Close();
        }
    }

    private void OnAlarmNotifyClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_alarmRaiseWindow != null)
        {
            _alarmRaiseWindow.Closed -= OnAlarmNotifyClosed
            _alarmRaiseWindow = null;
        }
    }
```

Here is a simplified version of the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.AlarmRaise"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Width="400" Height="300">
    <Border>
        <Grid>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RaisedAlarms, Mode=OneWay}">
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

**Edits**:

The way my code works is basically this.  When the first item in the collection is added it shows a `Window` containing a `ListBox` bound the collection, so if any others are added in the collection they will show as well.  Once the last item in the collection is removed, the `Window` is closed.

So say I have an "Alarm 1", "Alarm 2" and "Alarm 3", and they show the first time, and I remove them by sleeping them for five seconds, then the next time the window comes up, it will show the first item twice: "Alarm 1", "Alarm 1", "Alarm 2", "Alarm 3". Not always in that order.

This is true for subsequent iterations as well (i.e. it never shows up more than doubled).

**Further Edits**:

It seems that the issue is either with the view or the binding.  The view model is always showing the correct data at the correct times. I am wondering if maybe I need to refresh the binding in some way, or bind in code.  I am wanting to avoid both.

Comment: When it shows the second time, is it always a duplicate?  So if the first time you add an alarm called "Alarm 1" and the second time "Alarm 2", does it show "Alarm 1" and "Alarm 2" or does it show "Alarm 2" "Alarm 2"?

Comment: Yes, sir.  It is always a duplicate.

Comment: So it always shows "Alarm 2" "Alarm 2", if you show it a third time, does it show "Alarm 2" "Alarm 2" "Alarm 2", and so on?

Comment: Nope, it will only show it twice.  And it is always the first one that triggers the showing of the window.  So if I have an "Alarm 1", "Alarm 2" and "Alarm 3", and they show the first time, and I sleep them, then the next time the window comes up, it will show "Alarm 1", "Alarm 1", "Alarm 2", "Alarm 3".  Not always in that order. The second and third items are not triggering the window show they are just being added after the window is already there.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, I'm just trying to understand what's going on.  So in the scenario you describe, the `OnActiveAlarmsCollectionChanged` is fired twice, are you saying your application never fires it a third time, or you've just not tested what happens on the third time?  I suspect this is related to having your code running in the `OnCollectionModified` event.  As a test, can you launch a timer from the `OnCollectionModified` event and let that time show the window after say 100ms?

Comment: Are the initial alarms added differently from any new alarms? `.Contains()` checks an item by reference, not by value, so unless the new alarm is the exact same reference in memory as the initial alarm, the item will get added a 2nd time.

Comment: @CodingGorilla, OnActiveAlarmsCollection is not fired twice, it fires the correct number of times. The item only shows up in the view twice.  The view model doesn't seem to be the problem.

@Rachel, I know that `Contains` works by reference by default.  That was the first thing I checked.  The alarms are removed, but they are the same instance.  Again, the view model seems to work fine.  I've tested it and it gives me expected results.  It is the binding that is acting weird.

Answer (score 0):

Woo hoo, I've fixed the problem!  It had to do with the order of setting `DataContext` and calling `Show()`.  It works fine if I set the `DataContext` *after* I call `Window.Show()`.  Oops, I left out the call to `Show()` in my example code. I had to change the code it to remove an external dependency that was irrelevant to this issue and would have begged more questions. I will edit that currently.